# unable to get that data from sql to display in textbox what's wrong with the code?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, separator

I want to input a data from textbox1 (ex: NSB1000-PCP) and when I click textbox2 I want to display the  corresponding value of PCP which is PENTAX.
I was unable to get that data from SQL to display in textbox2.

What's wrong with the code?
(PCP = abbrev; PENTAX = comp)

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim connecting As String
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    connecting = "Data Source = ERIK\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = True; database = NSB1"
    conn = New SqlConnection(connecting)
    Dim text1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim words() As String
    Dim separator() As String = {"-"}
    words = text1.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim Query As String = words(1)
                   Query = "select comp from list where abbrev = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
        COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, conn)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        While reader.Read
            TextBox2.Text = reader("comp")
        End While
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: What is the value of the `HasRows` property of the data reader?

Comment: I think `database` parameter in the connection string is only used when you also use `AttachDbFileName`. In your case use `Initial Catalog=NSB1;`. Also if you are expecting just one row from the query use `ExecuteScalar`, not `ExecuteReader`. The `DataTable` is unused so delete it so it doesn't confuse you. Lastly, put something in your exception handler so you can see any exceptions.